# Getting Macro Error: Argument is not optional

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I have the following function in my Libre Office macro:

```
Function izracunajHash(geslo As String, zacetni_hash As Integer)
    If zacetni_hash = 1 Then
        izracunajHash = 5
    Else
        izracunajHash = 1
    End If
End Function
```

I call it this way inside `Sub Main`

```
print izracunajHash("Geslo", 5)
```

And it gives me the error `Argument not optional` on the second line of code `If zacetni_hash = 1 Then`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: icyfox, where is the insertion point (the blinking cursor) when you run the macro? Place it inside `sub main` if it is not and try again?

Comment: Siddharth Rout, thank you so much. This solved the issue, I had the insertion point in my function. Moving it down to sub main solved it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, in Libre Office, unlike in MS Office, it will let you execute the function directly...

Comment: Since this is a less know fact, I would recommend posting it as an answer and then accepting that answer.